# Proper way to save data in activity and fragment

Tags: android, screen-rotation

What's the proper way to save data in `activity` and `fragment` on configuration change? I have `activity` with `NavigationDrawer` and  I would like to save current selected position of item in ListView but also save data from `fragment`. I have tried to save objects in `onSaveInstanceState` of activity but in this case I can't save data in fragment (using `onSaveInstanceState` in fragment class). What's the proper way to save data in `activity` and its `fragment` on configuration change?

Comment: gunar have good answer, you can accept it if it helped you

Answer (score 1):

**A. Fragment** 
Maybe the best way to handle orientation changes is to call [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) in `onCreate`. In this way the fragment is detached, but its instance is not destroyed at orientation change. When the activity is recreated then the same fragment instance is attached. However you need to be very careful to not retain something from previous activity and lead to memory leaks.
The other option to retain data is to overwrite `onSaveInstanceState`.

**B. Activity**
Once you moved the heavy data in your fragment, then in theory you shouldn't worry too much on activity recreation. If you've properly setup unique ids for your views, Android should retain their previously input data. If you have some model data, then put in `savedInstance` bundle. Again: overwrite `onSaveInstanceState` and get the data from `onCreate` Bundle parameter.

Answer (score 0):

try to save it in SharedPreferences
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html